# In R, how can I create a data frame from multiple files, where each file contains the measurements for a separate category?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a file `A` containing the measurements for 10 subjects who received some treatment, and a file `B` containing the measurements for another 10 subjects who received a different treatment. I want to perform one-way analysis of variance, so I'm using R's `anova`/`aov` functions. However, `aov` expects the data to be in a data frame where the first column contains the category (i.e. here either `A` or `B`) and the second column contains the corresponding sample. How can I read the two files and automatically construct the data frame?

Comment: R cares not one whit about which order your columns are in but you might.  What are the kinds of measures in your files and how are they formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code I recently wrote to solve the same problem. For me, the data was in CSV files named `blahblah_series_trials.csv`, where the `blahblah` determined the experiment type.

```
filenames <- dir(".", "*.series_trials.csv")
types <- sub('.*?([a-zA_Z]*)_series_trials.*', '\\1', filenames)
data <- adply(data.frame(f=I(filenames), t=types), 1,
              with, cbind(read.csv(f), exp_type=t))
```

This reads each file, adds a column `exp_type` based on which file it came from, and binds it all into one data frame.

Comment: Nice. That's much more legible. I guess the `adply` should be `apply`?

Comment: @Vegard - perhaps, but probably not. `adply` is the name of a function from `plyr` package which takes an Array as an input and output a Data.frame, hence the ADply.

Comment: @Chase that would make a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this, so I'm putting up the solution here.

```
# Define a new function: files is a vector of file names.
# The return value is a data frame where the x column contains the category
# (the file name) and the y column contains the corresponding samples.
read.files <- function(files) {
    l <- lapply(files, function (x) read.table(x)$V1)
    return(data.frame(
        x = factor(unlist(lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) sapply(c(1:length(l[[i]])), function(x) files[i])))),
        y = unlist(l)
    ))
}

f <- read.files(c("A", "B"))

anova(aov(y ~ x, f))
```

The output of f would look something like:

```
   x    y
1  A 10.0
2  A 10.1
3  A 11.1
4  A 12.9
5  A 10.7
6  A  9.6
7  A 10.4
8  A 10.8
9  A 10.1
10 A  9.3
11 B 20.5
12 B 21.1
13 B 25.2
14 B 13.2
15 B 13.3
16 B 17.4
17 B 18.9
18 B 20.2
19 B 23.8
```

This works for an arbitrary number of files, but each file is restricted to a single column only. The files can have different number of rows.